# joblib.Load() doesn't work

Tags: scikit-learn, pickle, joblib

I have used `joblib.dump` to save my file and it is working properly. Now I want to access my `.pkl` file  using `joblib.load()` but get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 425, in load
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 285, in load_build
    Unpickler.load_build(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1226, in load_build
    for k, v in state.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: What version of scikit-learn are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your reference (the variable) it's a tuple.

I once had a similar problem, and the issue was that I had a "," at the end of the line. That was causing python to interpret the assignment as a tuple. Maybe thats your problem?